# Design bugado! (porém com cache funciona, "desbuga")

Tags: javascript, css, css3, rolamento, cache

Estava montando uma tabela com `scroll` e me deparei com o seguinte *bug* no css:

[image: bug]

Se eu aperto `f5` 2 vezes a tabela acaba se concertando e fica assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu limpo o cache(`ctrl + f5`) o erro volta...

Meu javascript que monta essa tabela com a função:

```
var alunos = [{"id":"1","nome":"U"},{"id":"2","nome":"Q"},.....];
var trAlunoTemplate = '<tr>    <td>[@id]</td>    <td>[@nome]</td>...</tr>';

function createTable(quantidade, ordem) {
    var table = "";
    alunos = sort(alunos, ordem);
    for (var i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        var tr = trAlunoTemplate;
        tr = tr.replace("[@nome]", alunos[i].nome);
        tr = tr.replace("[@id]", alunos[i].id);
        table += tr;
    }
    jQuery("table tbody").html(table);
}
createTable(jQuery("#quantView").val(), "nome");
```

Meu css:

```
#quantView {
    text-align: center;
    height: 12px;
}
.tabela-out {

    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
thead tr {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#939393+0,aaaaaa+48,d3d3d3+100&1+0,0.66+36,1+100 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(147,147,147,1) 0%, rgba(164,164,164,0.66) 36%, rgba(170,170,170,0.72) 48%, rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(147,147,147,1) 0%,rgba(164,164,164,0.66) 36%,rgba(170,170,170,0.72) 48%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(147,147,147,1) 0%,rgba(164,164,164,0.66) 36%,rgba(170,170,170,0.72) 48%,rgba(211,211,211,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#939393', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
tr, td {
    border: gray solid 1px;
    padding: 0% 1%;
}
```

Comment: Em que lugar do HTML você está chamando esse JavaScript?

Comment: no final de tudo

Comment: Tem como colocar o código no JSFiddle, JSBin, ou CodePen?

Comment: Ta incluindo o CSS antes do carregamento da tabela?

Comment: Tenta assim: `jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
/* aqui vai seu código */
});`

Comment: Douglas: https://jsfiddle.net/xwfpyje4/10/ No jsfiddle quando eu redimenciono o lugar do resultado la ele concerta, no meu localhost só concerta quando fica no cache

Comment: Mau humor: já tentei colocar antes, depois e até no meio e também já tentei o ready...